# USB Error 2: Invalid Parameter on Windows 7, Not on Ubuntu

Tags: java, windows-7, libusb, ubuntu-14.04, usb4java

I'm working on a semi-cross platform USB Control Library in Java for a custom USB transceiver.
Most of the work was done in Ubuntu, and for a short while the control library (and the form I built to test it) worked just fine (except that the form wouldn't close for some reason). Then, I changed something. I don't remember what it was, but evidently whatever it was completely broke half the functionality (the part where I can still read from the transceiver, but I can't write to it).

This is MADDENING.

Anyway, the code for the writer component is here:

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

package JR3Controller;

import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import org.usb4java.DeviceHandle;
import org.usb4java.LibUsb;
import org.usb4java.LibUsbException;
import org.usb4java.Transfer;
/**
 *
 * @author Will
 */
public class JR3Writer {

    private final DeviceHandle devH;
    public JR3Writer(DeviceHandle devH){
        this.devH = devH;
    }

    private void sendData(byte[] barrData) throws LibUsbException {
        ByteBuffer cXferSetup = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(13);
        Transfer xFer = LibUsb.allocTransfer();
        LibUsb.fillControlSetup(
                cXferSetup, (byte)0x21, (byte)0x9,
                (byte)0x200, (byte)0x0, (byte)0x5
        );
        cXferSetup.put(barrData);
        LibUsb.fillControlTransfer(xFer, devH, cXferSetup, null, xFer, 0);
        this.errCheck(
            "Unable to communicate with remote",
            LibUsb.submitTransfer(xFer)
        );
    }

    public void allLightsOn(){
        this.sendData(new byte[]{
            (byte)0x63, (byte)0x6D, (byte)0x64, (byte)0xC9, (byte)0x00
        });
    }

    public void allLightsOut(){
        this.sendData(new byte[]{
                    (byte)0x63, (byte)0x6D, (byte)0x64, (byte)0xCB, (byte)0x00
        });
    }

    public void on(int Player){
        this.sendData(new byte[]{
           (byte)0x63, (byte)0x6D, (byte)0x64, (byte)(0x29 + Player), (byte)0x00
        });
    }

    public void onFive(int Player){
        this.sendData(new byte[]{
           (byte)0x63, (byte)0x6D, (byte)0x64, (byte)(0x1 + Player), (byte)0x00
        });
    }

    public void flash(int Player){
        this.sendData(new byte[]{
           (byte)0x63, (byte)0x6D, (byte)0x64, (byte)(0x51 + Player), (byte)0x00
        });
    }

    public void off(int Player){
        this.sendData(new byte[]{
           (byte)0x63, (byte)0x6D, (byte)0x64, (byte)(0x79 + Player), (byte)0x00
        });
    }

    private void errCheck(String msg, int r) throws LibUsbException{
        if (r < 0) throw new LibUsbException(msg, r);
    }
}
```

Why would this work just FINE in Ubuntu and fail miserably in Windows? I was working under the presumption Java was cross-platform, meant to work fine without any changes from one OS to the next.

Also, I read the Control Transfer from the USB Sniffer (that I can only assume is when the device is written to). The package setup was this: `0x21 0x9 0x0 0x2 0x0 0x0 0x5 0x0`

I don't really know what else to do to make this work. The error message wasn't very useful, and I'm hoping maybe someone else has run into this and may be able to help me.